Writing $\frac{dM}{dt}(t)$ for $M(t)$ being a stochastic process.
In the paper, the equation 2.35 is an implicit form of a stochastic differential equation.
Here is the excerpt from the paper:

The implicit form of a stochastic differential equation is given as
$$\dot x(t) = \chi(x(t))\mu(t). \tag{2.35}$$
Here, $\chi(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$ and $\mu(t)$ is a possibly stochastic function defined by
$$\mu(t) = \frac{dM}{dt}(t),$$
where $dM(t)$ could be $dt$ (deterministic), $dW(t)$ (diffusive), $dP(t)$ (Poisson) or some other stochastic increment. The normal rules of calculus apply in the implicit form because $\mu(t)$ is acting as if it were a smooth function of time.

I'm confused by several seemingly contradicting statements:

Why does writing $\frac{dM}{dt}$ make any sense for $dM=dW$ (or any other stochastic increment)?
How can $\mu(t)$ be a smooth function if we let $dM=dW$ (or any other stochastic increment)?
What is the intuition behind the "implicit" form?

Next, the author gives an explicit form of the equation 2.35, which is
$$\left \{ \frac{d}{ds} x(s) = \chi(x(s))\frac{dM(t)}{dt} \right \}_{s=t}. \tag{2.40}$$
Since I do not understand items 1), 2) and 3), I can't comprehend the equation 2.40 as well.
